Vite + Electron - how to add external project as child process
In my main project files, I added a directory "/api" that contains API files in JS.
I can run the project successfully, but only in development mode (npm run dev). When I run npm run build:win, it's not working.
import { app, shell, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } from 'electron'
import { fork } from 'child_process'
import { join } from 'path'
import { electronApp, optimizer, is } from '@electron-toolkit/utils'

fork('api/main.js') //<- works ok only in dev

function createWindow(): void {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 370,
    height: 600,
    show: false,
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: join(__dirname, '../preload/index.js'),
      sandbox: false
    }
  })

What is the correct way to reference these files? Do I need to add something to the config to include my API folder in the final build?

In production __dirname will resolve to the ASAR.  To combat this, use app.getAppPath() if the app is packaged:
const { app } = require('electron');

const rootPath = app.isPackaged ? app.getAppPath() : __dirname;

